# How can we compare elastic-net regularisation v.s equentially applying lasso and ridge regression?

Tags: regression, regularization

If we use the below formulation of elastic-net penalisation:

$$\beta^{EN} = {\rm argmin} \left( \lVert X-X\beta \rVert_2 +\lambda ( \alpha \lVert x \rVert_1 +(1-\alpha)\lVert x \rVert_2\right)$$

I could imagine that instead of doing the above, we first apply a lasso solve to select a subset of regressors & then apply ridge regression to this subset to normalise.

I have a few questions about the two approaches (elastic net v.s sequential application of the params):
Can we say anything about the relative behaviour of the 2 methods?

We should expect that the elastic net estimator has higher variance v.s doing sequential regularization, so how could we compare the relative performance between the 2 models to account for the increased degrees of freedom in the first approach?